# Testing multiple browsers with different options using WebDriver, Nunit and C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, nunit

I am trying to run a test on multiple browsers using WebDriver, Nunit and C#.  It's working, but I am getting that annoying security warning in Chrome.  In an effort to fix it, I need to re-create the driver using ".AddArguments("--test-type"); ".  But I only want to do this if this iterations browser = Chrome.  Here is my code.  It works, but it launches an un-needed browser window first.  Anybody have any idea's around this?

```
   namespace SeleniumTests
   {
        [TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
        [TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
        [TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]

        public class TestWithMultipleBrowsers<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
        {
             private IWebDriver driver;

             [SetUp]
             public void CreateDriver()
             {
                  this.driver = new TWebDriver();  //Creates a window that needs to be closed and re-constructed

                  if(driver is ChromeDriver)
                  {
                       driver.Quit();      //This kills the un-needed driver window created above
                       var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                       chromeOptions.AddArguments("--test-type"); 
                       driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
                  }
             }
```

Comment: You've instantly hit a code structure problem. Your being generic and specific at the same time. Pick one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do not you simpley create the chromedriver in the base class well? you can also use the `chromoptions` there to pass necessary arguments. Then use

```
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
```

That will save you unncessary code duplication and confusion as well.

I have a full implementation of driver instances [here](https://github.com/safrrhmn/protractor-net-pageobject/blob/master/Tests/TestHelpers/WebDriverFactory.cs)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are invoking chrome twice in your code. Here is a sample code which might help you.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;


namespace MultipleBrowserTesting
{
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
public class BlogTest<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;

    [Test]
    public void Can_Visit_Google()
    {
        _driver = new TWebDriver();

        // Navigate
        _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void FixtureTearDown()
    {
        if (_driver != null) 
            _driver.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Here is a link to the Github project.
[GitHub Link to solution](https://github.com/Vishwa1/MultipleBrowserTesting-Solution)